# Could not find method srcDirs() for arguments on SourceSet container of type org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultSourceSetContainer

Tags: gradle, kotlin, build.gradle, kotlin-js

I'm trying to compile my Kotlin app and set of Kotlin libraries to JavaScript. I've got that working well, but when I try to run it, [it can't find `kotlin.js`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53582651/3939277). To remedy this, I tried changing my `build.gradle` to be more like [this example on GitHub](https://github.com/bascan/kotlin-js-example/blob/master/build.gradle).

In mine, I defined source sets like this: (which works but doesn't output `kotlin.js`)

```kotlin
sourceSets {
    main {
        kotlin {
            srcDirs 'src/main/kotlin'
        }
    }
}
```

to something like this: (which doesn't even sync)

```
sourceSets {
    main.kotlin.srcDirs += "src/main/kotlin"
}
```

which gives me this error:

```
Could not find method srcDirs() for arguments [lib/Blue-Base/src/main/kotlin] on SourceSet container of type org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultSourceSetContainer.
```

How do I resolve this error? I know one issue is I don't quite grok Groovy/Gradle, but I feel like what I did should at least sync...

---

Here's a link to the code and project in question: https://github.com/BlueHuskyStudios/Decision-Cruncher/blob/SO/53576840/build.gradle

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you have written `srcDirs` instead of `main.kotlin.srcDirs`.

Comment: Where? inside `main { kotlin {`? I think it's implied in there. When I flatten it, I write it out...

Comment: My suggestion is to replace `srcDirs` with `main.kotlin.srcDirs +=` here https://github.com/BlueHuskyStudios/Decision-Cruncher/blob/d23add9518946115c631f0628c184826fd69b7d9/build.gradle#L28 and other.