# Gradle doesn't emit kotlin.js

Tags: gradle, kotlin, build.gradle, kotlin-js

I'm trying to compile my Kotlin app and set of Kotlin libraries to JavaScript. I've got that working well, but when I try to run it it can't find `kotlin.js`.

**So what's going on here?** When I compile using IDEA (instead of Gradle), it outputs `kotlin.js` just fine. I tried making my build script more like an example I found, [but that wouldn't compile](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53576840/3939277)...

---

Here's a link to the code and project in question: https://github.com/BlueHuskyStudios/Decision-Cruncher/blob/SO/q/53582651/1/build.gradle

Comment: Please accompany any downvotes with a comment letting me know why my question shows no research effort, is unclear, andor is not useful. That way I can write better questions in the future 

Comment: Have you read this doc: [Using Gradle](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/using-gradle.html)

Comment: Looks like you already have found a solution.

Comment: @bashor Why do you say that?

Comment: @Kousic yes that's where I got most of my build.gradle script

Comment: @BenLeggiero Did you figure it out in the end? Facing the same issue and starting to pull my hair

Comment: @AlexandreG It's been out of my head for a few months, but I seem to recall wiping the slate clean (something that I often do because I didn't want to deal with a problem anymore, and which works disturbingly often). Uninstalled IDEA and deleted all non-code files, then re-installed IDEA and created a new project from those sources. Maybe the same could work for you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any others struggling in the future, I've had the following issue:

IntelliJ Kotlin/JS starter project has been generated with this in the gradle file:

`implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-js"`

which needs to be this to get the `kotlin.js` file

`compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-js"`

Answer (score 2):

This only worked for me. `unzip` for some reason was no working

```
task assembleWeb() {
    configurations.implementation.setCanBeResolved(true)
    configurations.implementation.each { File file ->
        if (file.path.indexOf('kotlin-stdlib-js') >= 0) {
            exec {
                workingDir "$projectDir/web"
                standardOutput = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
                commandLine "7z", "e", file.absolutePath, "kotlin.js", "-aos", "-r"
            }
        }
    }
    dependsOn classes
}

assemble.dependsOn assembleWeb
```

Be aware of `"-aos"` param. This flag will prevent from overwriting of existing file

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/javascript/getting-started-gradle/getting-started-with-gradle.html) you can find the code snippet to extract all .js files from Kotlin/JS libraries:

```
task assembleWeb(type: Sync) {
    configurations.compile.each { File file ->
        from(zipTree(file.absolutePath), {
            includeEmptyDirs = false
            include { fileTreeElement ->
                def path = fileTreeElement.path
                path.endsWith(".js") && (path.startsWith("META-INF/resources/") || 
                    !path.startsWith("META-INF/"))
            }
        })
    }
    from compileKotlin2Js.destinationDir
    into "${projectDir}/web"

    dependsOn classes
}

assemble.dependsOn assembleWeb
```

Comment: [I've tried placing that in my build.gradle script](https://github.com/BlueHuskyStudios/Decision-Cruncher/blob/SO/53582651/a/3939277/c/1/build.gradle#L90-L106) and it doesn't work

Comment: This literally does nothing. The output is completely unchanged... My whole codebase is available for you to [clone and see for yourself](https://github.com/BlueHuskyStudios/Decision-Cruncher/blob/SO/53582651/a/3939277/c/1/build.gradle#L90-L106)